# Interactive console command in symfony (PHP)

Tags: symfony, console, interactive, ansi-escape, reactphp

There are console programs, like an editor (say: `nano` for example) or like a system monitor (say: `htop`) where you can "navigate" with arrows and freely interact with the content.

In this example, for example I have executed `htop` and while it's running I've pressed arrow-down multiple times until the PID 14 has been selected:

[image: htop with PID 14 selected]

In Symfony I can easily print and also format with colors with the `OutputInterface` that is injected into the commands.

But... can this "interactivity" be achieved easily with PHP and symfony console commands?

For the sake of the example: Could I code a simple "snake" game in PHP/symfony/console?

(PD: If needed, I MAY use ReactPhp to handle the event loop).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! This is an excellent use case for ReactPHP, especially if you're looking to create something interactive and reactive. I highly recommend checking out https://github.com/clue/reactphp-stdio, as it perfectly fits your use case.

Comment: Have you personally tried to code with clue/reactphp-stdio yourself?

Comment: Interesting article. I also like to use it but I cannot see how to implement it with symfony and twig template.

Can someone give a documentation or an example?